# set a csh command with options within ""

Tags: csh

I am writing a `csh` script and I need to execute a command that from the prompt would be:

> $ command -c ":var = a + b"

So I try:

> set cmd = "command -c "'":var = a + b"'" -o outfile"
>   echo $cmd
>   $cmd

The string `cmd` is shown correctly with the echo. But when I try to execute `$cmd` I get an error saying that the argument that of the `-c` option is not recognized. The error reports: = a + b"

> I.e, the :var part is missing.

Any advice?

Comment: don't use `csh`? Seriously! . This sort of problem is tough in any shell language and it all about being able to manipulate the quoting properly. There are places in csh quoting that "just don't work as they should" and what you're trying to do is right is that biggest of csh's weak spots. There are many other reasons not to do scripting in csh, search the web for `csh considered harmful` and `csh whynot`. If you must continue, find the old O'Reilly Unix Power Tools book and read thru all the stuff about csh. Finally , use a shebang like `#!/bin/csh -fvx` ... `vx` giving you debug/trace. GoodL

Comment: A few other comments. Also forgot to plug the really best book about `csh`  http://www.amazon.com/The-Unix-Shell-Field-Guide/dp/013937468X . The most sympathetic online resource for csh that I know of is http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html  (Start there). If you must persist, and you don't know about  the `eval` cmd, then it may help you, but it will take some time to understand AND it generally considered as the spawn of satan, so be prepared for that when you post a Q with `eval`. Finally, if you really need this functionality you'll find it sooooo much more extensible in ksh or bash

Answer (score 0):

I will go one step further than @shellter, and say it cannot be done in CSH or TCSH.

CSH parsing is very simplistic, and either expands variables or not. And if it does, it doesn't then honour quotes that it finds in those variables. In other words, the parser is not recursive.

So you can't even do this:

```
args="-c 'with space'"
command $args
command "$args"
```

The first version will pass `-c`, `with` and `space` to the command, the second version will pass `-c with space`.